# How to interpret this Emacs magit help screen?

Tags: git, emacs, magit

I'm beginning to learn about the `magit` package for Emacs. The integration is nice. But I'm very confused about how to get help with it.

I created a temporary repository, added a file `test.org` to it and ran the command `magit-status`. Then I hit `?` to get help. I figured that this means it displays the command available to me inside the magit-status screen. The screen looks like the following:

[image: screenshot]

At the bottom are the magit actions available. Notice how it says `s: Show Status`. But `s` doesn't do that. It stages a file. And there is no `u` key, but it unstages a file.

Am I misreading this or am I invoking the wrong help screen or something else?

Comment: Is your caps lock depressed by chance -- capital `S` is *Stage All*?  See line 1622:  https://github.com/magit/magit/blob/master/magit.el

Comment: No, I checked that. Not caps lock.

Comment: Its possible then, perhaps, that the `magit-status-mode-map` is active during the help screen -- which pressing the lower-case letter `s` would trigger `magit-stage-item` at line 1644 in the above-linked source code.  If that is the case, it sounds like a bug . . .  The library is very popular and another forum participant will likely have the answer shortly.  Changing line 1644 from a lower-case `s` to an upper-case `S` would probably fix the problem,  and then re-byte-compiling and restarting Emacs.

Comment: I was slightly mistaken. I pressed `?` instead of `h`. The `?` key is bound to `magit-key-mode-popup-dispatch` and the `h` is bound to `magit-key-mode-popup-diff-options`. I'm not sure if it makes a difference, but even in the `h` key help screen there is no "stage" and "unstage" described.

Comment: I'm not sure why this happens, but it seems like hitting `s` while this help screen is open _does_ run the "view status" command (i.e. `magit-status`), not the "stage" command.

Answer (score 2):

`magit` offers a form of context menus which fits with a keyboard-based input. Hence the key-binding depend on which menu you are in. Somewhat counter-intuitively, `?` does not open the mode specific help (use `C-h m` for that, as usual). `?` opens up the top level context menu, by invoking `magit-key-mode-popup-dispatch`. When in this menu, the available keybindings are different from those on invoking `magit-status`. In the status mode, `s` and `u` are bound to `magit-stage-item` and `magit-unstage-item`. Since they act on the item at point, it doesn't make sense to bind a key to them when in one of the context menus. Given this consideration, binding `s` to `"Show Status"` in the context menu launched by `?` is quite natural.